# How do I create a code that prints randomly picked letters until it can spell the word I want

Tags: python, loops

What I want to with this code is to be able to randomly pick a letter from the list i've created until it spells out the word coffee. Here is what I have so far.

```
import random
def repeat():
    items = ["c", "o", "f", "e"]
    coffee_choice = random.choice(items)

items = ["c", "o", "f", "e"]

coffee_choice = random.choice (items)

print(coffee_choice)
```

UPDATE: I've just realized how the things i said didn't make sense at all so i'll explain it better this time, thanks to those who provided working code unfortunately not what im after. If possible could you provide some explanation in each part of the code on how it works. (trying to learn it!)

Step 1: I need to be able to choose a random letter (done this)

Step 2: Choose letters util the word COFFEE can be spelled out.

Step 3: Display the letters that have been chosen and then state the amount of times/attempts were needed to get all of the letters.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "have the list update per attempt"? And also what constitutes an attempt (e.g., if you successfully spell "coffee", does it require a minimum of 6 attempts)?

Answer (score 1):

To build a six-letter string from letters randomly chosen from "c", "o", "f", "e", you'll want to make six `random.choice`s, and then `join` them together to make a single string:

```
>>> "".join(random.choice("cofe") for _ in range(6))
'focooc'
```

So now if you want to do that until it makes "coffee":

```
>>> attempts = 1
>>> while "coffee" != "".join(random.choice("cofe") for _ in range(6)):
...     attempts += 1
... else:
...     print(f"it took {attempts} attempts to make coffee!")
...
it took 9873 attempts to make coffee!
```

---

Note that you can increase the odds of getting a particular letter (and decrease the number of tries) if you add more of them to the iterable you pass to `random.choice`:

```
>>>
>>> attempts = 1
>>> while "coffee" != "".join(random.choice("coffee") for _ in range(6)):
...     attempts += 1
... else:
...     print(f"it took {attempts} attempts to make coffee!")
...
it took 1282 attempts to make coffee!
```

and greatly decrease the odds by adding more letters that you don't need:

```
>>> attempts = 1
>>> while "coffee" != "".join(random.choice("abcdefghijklmno") for _ in range(6)):
...     attempts += 1
... else:
...     print(f"it took {attempts} attempts to make coffee!")
...
it took 4683223 attempts to make coffee!
```

Comment: Apologies for the bad answer, I've updated the post with clearer information, I've also replied to another comment.

Comment: This code does exactly what you asked for in your updated post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want (this can be shortened a bit but I've written it out explicitly for easy understanding):

```
import random

def spell_word(word, items):
  numOfLetters = len(word)
  attempt = ""

  for i in range(0, numOfLetters):
    attempt += random.choice(items)

  if attempt != word:
    print("Failed to spell {word}, spelled {attempt} instead".format(word=word, attempt=attempt))
    return False
  else:
    print("Spelled correctly!") 
    return True

limit = 100000
items = ["c", "o", "f", "e"]
for i in range(0, limit):
  if spell_word("coffee", items):
    print("Took {} tries.".format(i))
    break
  else:
    pass # do something to the items list
```

**Edit: different code after further explanation from OP:**

```
import random

def spell_word(word, items, attempts):
  """
  Tries to spell the given word using randomly picked letters from items
  """
  attempts = ""
  wordLen = len(word)

  for i in range(0, limit):
    attempts += random.choice(items)
    if len(attempts) >= wordLen and attempts[-wordLen:] == word:
      print("Spelled correctly after {} tries!".format(i+1))
      break

  print("All attempted letters ({} letters picked):".format(len(attempts)))
  print(attempts)

limit = 50000
items = ["c", "o", "f", "e"]
spell_word("coffee", items, limit)
```

Comment: I knew i'd mess up the explanation and I apologize. Alright so basically I need to be able to    1: Choose a random letter.   2: Continue to choose random letters until the word coffee can be spelled out.  3: Display all the 'letters' that have been chosen and then state how many times/attempts were needed to get all the letters. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Okay so what I understand is: You want to keep choosing 1 random character from the 26 alphabets until you end up with all of c,o,f,e (in that order?) that will allow you to spell coffee? And you want to display all the randomly selected letters (and consequently how many random picks it took to get all of c,o,f,e?

Comment: Pretty much! Just don't want all letters in the alphabet, only c, o, f, e are needed. I've updated the post with better details on what to do. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: If you only want to choose from c,o,f,e then the above code already does exactly that. If I'm still not understanding your question, can you provide example input to a function, and the corresponding example output? Then I can help provide an implementation

Comment: Yeah actually you're 100% correct it does. It gives every word attempt. But what if i wanted just the letters. So how many letters until i have all the letters to spell c o f f e e ? So it would add a letter to the list every attempt. e.g [c] [c] [c] [c] [o] [o] [f] [e] . Sorry can't really provide examples of anything, it's really confusing for me.

Comment: Ok I added another piece of code - does this look like what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to choose))

```
import random
def repeat():
    items = ["c", "o", "f", "e"]
    return random.choice(items)

isNotSpelled = True;
letters_spelled = ""
while isNotSpelled:
    letters_spelled+=repeat()
    length = len(letters_spelled)
    if length>=6:
        if(letters_spelled[length-6:length])=="coffee":
            isNotSpelled = False;
print(len(letters_spelled))
```

The output is the number of spelled letters (attempts) until "coffee" appears

```
1434
```